# Running Instruments to check for leaks on iPhone without developer license

Tags: iphone, xcode, instruments

I'm trying to run Instruments on an iPhone app that I've compiled as debug, self signed (no developer license), and copied to the phone.

If I select run with with Instruments from Xcode, first the Organizer will complain that the app is already installed, and Instruments doesn't do anything.  If I try to go directly from Instruments, my app is not listed the in pull-down menu of available processes.

Oh, and I can't run the app in the simulator because the dylib that I'm using is compiled for ARM, and if I select the simulator (which changes the architecture to i386), the source will fail to compile.

Any thing obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: What do you mean by 'without developer license'? Aren't you enrolled in the iOS Developer Program?

Comment: I am signed up so I can access the SDK and documentation.  However, I don't have an official developer signature with which to sign my apps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you need to be enrolled in the [iOS Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/start/standard/) (yearly paid subscription) in order to sign and run applications on your testing devices. The only alternative to avoid paying is to go the jailbreak route (which I won't provide details about, despite being legal in some countries such as the US).

Comment: My phone is jailbroken, and I can self sign and run the app just fine on my phone.  I'm just trying to run instruments to check for any leaks and where to optimize.